# Make react-select 2.0.0 <Async> work with redux-form <Field>

Tags: redux-form, react-select

`react-select` just upgraded to 2.0.0 so google results on the first three pages are all about older versions, even the [official document](https://react-select.com/async), and none of them helped.

My select box can show all options correctly, but redux form won't pick up the value, with the warning: `Warning: A component is changing a controlled input of type hidden to be uncontrolled.`

I wonder what have I missed here...

Form component:

```
<Field
  name="residentialAddress"
  label = "Residential Address"
  type="select"
  component={AddressField}
  validate={required}
/>
```

Component

```
export class AddressField extends Component {

    searchAddress = input => {
        let options = []

        return myPromise(input)
        .then(suggestions => {
                options = suggestions.map(suggestion => 
                    ({
                        label: suggestion.label,
                        data: suggestion.value
                    })
                )
                return options;             
            }
        ).catch(
            error => { 
                return options = [{ label: "Auto fetching failed, please enter your address manually", value: "", isDisabled: true }];
            }
        );
    };

    render() {
        const {
            input,
            label,
            meta: { touched, error },
            type
        } = this.props;

        return(
            <FormGroup>
                <ControlLabel>{label}</ControlLabel>
                <Async
                    {...input}
                    placeholder={label}
                    isClearable={true}   
                    getOptionValue={(option) => option.residentialAddress}
                    onChange = { value => input.onChange(value.data) }
                    loadOptions={this.searchAddress}                   
                />
                { touched && error && <span>{error}</span> }
            </FormGroup>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Simply remove the `{...input}` in `<Async>`.

Unlike regular custom Field component where we need to pass in `{input}`, the react-select Async component seems to take care of itself very well and doesn't require any intervene. Someone may explain it in a more professional way perhaps...

Also worth mention for those who come across this question: 
`loadOptions` with promise used to require object `{options: options}` as return type. Now it changes to just array (`options` as in my code). But I didn't find any document that mentions this one.

Hope this could help.